# Wordpress functions not working outside of root wordpress directory

Tags: wordpress

Not quite sure why this is happening, hopefully someone can help. I have a wordpress installation, lets say for arguments sake it's installed to `http://www.example.com/wordpress`. I have a file called test.php with the following code:

```
<?php
include '/php_path_to_blog/wp-blog-header.php';
echo get_current_user_id();
?>
```

Now the odd part is if i have a user logged in and place this file within my wordpress directory and call it by going to `http://www.example.com/wordpress/test.php` it outputs the correct user id of the current logged in user. However if I move the file to the root directory of the site and call it by going to `http://www.example.com/test.php`, it outputs 0 as if there were no user logged in.

It seems that some functions work properly outside of the installation directory and some don't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you state what version of Wordpress you're using. This will help potential responders give the most accurate answer.

Comment: Could it be that the user cookie is set on /wordpress and thus not available in root?

Answer (score 1):

Please declare varaibale global $wpdb; I think this will work.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
include '/php_path_to_blog/wp-blog-header.php'; 
echo get_current_user_id();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

1. You're using include, not require. See WP Codex for [instructions and examples on doing this right](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_Wordpress_with_Your_Website).
2. Function method/name are incorrect. [Function Reference/get currentuserinfo - Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)
3. Trying to do the echo within the include. See first link for proper examples of site integration.